# FFMPEG : add multiple drawtexts, vertically stacked, to a video

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I wish to add several texts to a video. The texts should be vertically aligned, in the top center of the video.
here is what I tried for now :

```
n = len(titles) #Titles a list containing all the texts we will add to the video
p = 0
for text in titles:
    os.system(
        fr'ffmpeg -i output{p}.mp4 -filter:v drawtext="fontfile=Lato- 
        Black.ttf:fontcolor=black:fontsize=60:text=' + f"'{text}':" + f'y=200-{(n-p) * 62}:x=(w- 
        text_w)/2"-y output{p + 1}.mp4')
    p = p + 1
```

As you can see, all the texts should have x=(w- text_w)/2 as their abscissa (which is constant?), but they're never aligned. There is always a sort of padding that pushes the next text added, a bit more to the right.
I also tried to use x=w/2 which is constant and the texts are still not vertically aligned.

Comment: Carry it out in one command and check. Separate each drawtext instance with a comma.

Comment: Done, but the texts are still not vertically aligned .